# Access parent form property using template pattern with React and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I created a base generic form component that I was planning to reuse across other child form components. So I have these 2 files:

BaseForm.tsx

```
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form"

export const BaseForm = ({
  children, // (methods: any) => React.ReactNode
  onSubmit,
}) => {
  const methods = useForm()
  const { handleSubmit } = methods
  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate={true}>
        {children(methods)}
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  )
}
```

Child.tsx

```
export const ContactForm = () => {
  const methods = useFormContext()  // does not work
  const onSubmit = data => {
    // ... logic goes here
    // and then do something with methods here, like reset form, etc
  }

  return (
    <BaseForm onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {(methods) => (
        <>
          <TextField
            {...methods.register("field1")}
          />
          // other input fields ...
        </>
      )}
    </BaseForm>
  )
}
```

With this example, I am trying to access `methods` from `useForm` from the `ChildForm` which was initialized on the `BaseForm`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please perhaps create a functioning example ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This question looks perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply call the `useForm` function in the parent component (`ContactForm`) instead of in the child component (`BaseForm`), and then pass it as an argument to the child component.

---

`ContactForm.tsx`

```
export const ContactForm = () => {
  const methods = useForm() // <-- note this line

  const onSubmit = data => {
    // ... logic goes here
    // and then do something with methods here, like reset form, etc
  }

  return (
    <BaseForm onSubmit={onSubmit} methods={methods}>
      {/* no closure needed here */}
        
          <TextField
            {...methods.register("field1")}
          />
          {/* other input fields ... */}
        
      
    </BaseForm>
  )
}
```

`BaseForm.tsx`

```
export const BaseForm = ({
  children,
  onSubmit,
  methods,
}) => {
  // methods is simply passed as an argument now
  // const methods = useForm()  <-- this isn't needed anymore

  const { handleSubmit } = methods

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate={true}>
        {children}
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's fair, but I would still like to have ```useForm``` on ```BaseForm``` because I have some props defined there which I wouldn't like to repeat them for each child form component.

Comment: @renatodamas You could create a wrapper function for any form-like component that calls `useForm` and wraps the returned React elements in the `FormProvider`. If you want I could write an example of that for you in the TS Playground.

Comment: @renatodamas Here is an example anyway: https://t.ly/ovyr (note that I haven't tested it but the idea should be clear)